# If close(2) fails with EIO, will the file descriptor still be deleted?

Tags: c, unix, posix, system-calls

If a close(2) system call fails with EIO, will the file descriptor still be deleted?

If yes, is it not possible to handle a spurious IO error by retrying later? If no, how should one prevent a file descriptor leak?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's a tricky question.  However, the POSIX standard does cover it in the description of [`close()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html):

> If close() is interrupted by a signal that is to be caught, it shall return -1 with errno set to [EINTR] and the state of fildes is unspecified. If an I/O error occurred while reading from or writing to the file system during close(), it may return -1 with errno set to [EIO]; if this error is returned, the state of fildes is unspecified.

So, the state of the file descriptor is unspecified by the standard.

For most practical purposes, it is closed; there is precious little you can do with the file descriptor even if it is officially open.  You could try an innocuous operation (like `fcntl()` and `F_GETFL`) and see whether you get EBADF back, indicating the descriptor is formally closed.  But if it is open and the cause of the EIO error is permanent, then you're likely to get EIO every time you try to do anything with it (possibly including the `fcntl()` call).  You might or might not ever get the same descriptor returned by another open-like operation.  It is not clear that even `dup2()` could be successful specifying the 'dead' file descriptor as the target if the dead file descriptor is open but uncloseable.

Comment: If your program is multithreaded or uses signal handlers then testing the file descriptor using `fcntl()` may not be as straightforward, since it may have been closed and then reused for something else.

Comment: Is this a problem if one uses a non stdio framework like libuv?

Comment: Yes, this is a problem in any framework built using `open()`, `close()` and relatives, so unless `libuv` uses a different set of system calls than `open()` and `close()` (which is pretty improbable), it could suffer from problems with `close()` failing and leaving the file descriptor in an indeterminate state.

Comment: What about trying to close() again the file descriptor once EIO is received?

Comment: @MarcoPagliaricci: The state of the file descriptor is unspecified.  It may have been closed and the file descriptor reused so the retry might be closing something else.  Weird (and rather unlikely), but so.  It really isn't safe to do anything with a file descriptor if `close()` fails except, perhaps, report that the problem occurred.

Comment: I agree. It's better to trust the operating system doing the right thing, e.g. not memory leaking, etc.