# What can cause close(2) to fail with EIO for a read-only file?

Tags: java, android, c, linux, posix

I'm investigating a problem on Android where an `IOException` is getting thrown because of a failure to close a file:

```
java.io.IOException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
    at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:41)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.close(FileInputStream.java:121)
    at com.adamrosenfield.wordswithcrosses.io.JPZIO.convertJPZPuzzle(JPZIO.java:191)
    at com.adamrosenfield.wordswithcrosses.net.AbstractJPZDownloader.download(AbstractJPZDownloader.java:56)
    at com.adamrosenfield.wordswithcrosses.net.AbstractJPZDownloader.download(AbstractJPZDownloader.java:41)
    at com.adamrosenfield.wordswithcrosses.net.AbstractDownloader.download(AbstractDownloader.java:112)
    at com.adamrosenfield.wordswithcrosses.net.AbstractDownloader.download(AbstractDownloader.java:108)
    at com.adamrosenfield.wordswithcrosses.net.Downloaders.download(Downloaders.java:257)
    at com.adamrosenfield.wordswithcrosses.BrowseActivity.internalDownload(BrowseActivity.java:702)
    at com.adamrosenfield.wordswithcrosses.BrowseActivity.access$6(BrowseActivity.java:696)
    at com.adamrosenfield.wordswithcrosses.BrowseActivity$7.run(BrowseActivity.java:691)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EIO (I/O error)
    at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
    at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:38)
    ... 11 more
```

The relevant code:

```
public static void convertJPZPuzzle(File jpzFile, File destFile,
        PuzzleMetadataSetter metadataSetter) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(jpzFile);
    try {
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destFile));
        try {
            if (!convertJPZPuzzle(fis, dos, metadataSetter)) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to convert JPZ file: " + jpzFile);
            }
        } finally {
            dos.close();
        }
    } finally {
        fis.close();
    }
}
```

The full source is [on GitHub](https://github.com/adamantoise/wordswithcrosses/blob/master/wordswithcrosses/src/com/adamrosenfield/wordswithcrosses/io/JPZIO.java).

The exception is being thrown from the line `fis.close()`.  From what I can tell from reading the Android sources, it looks like `FileInputStream.close()` just calls down into [`close(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close) on the underlying file descriptor in native code.

The manual pages don't seem to specify what can cause an `EIO` error, they just say things like "An I/O error occurred." or "If an I/O error occurred while reading from or writing to the file system during close()".  The Mac OS X man pages say it can occur when "A previously-uncommitted write(2) encountered an input/output error." on those systems.

What exactly can cause `close(2)` to fail with the error `EIO` for a file descriptor which was only opened for reading, as in this case?  Clearly it's not an uncommitted `write(2)`.  In the case of this particular file, it was downloaded using Android's DownloadManager service, which means there might be lingering threads and/or processes trying to access it simultaneously, but I can hardly see how that would affect trying to close it.  Also, the file is just about to be deleted after this code runs ([here](https://github.com/adamantoise/wordswithcrosses/blob/master/wordswithcrosses/src/com/adamrosenfield/wordswithcrosses/net/AbstractJPZDownloader.java#L58)), but unless Android has an undocumented time machine in it, future code ought not to have an affect here.

I'm interested specifically in the answer on Android and/or Linux, but a more general answer for other OSes would also be appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't get very far because I don't know `c` or `posix` systems. Related question and answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297001/if-close2-fails-with-eio-will-the-file-descriptor-still-be-deleted). Source code for `libcore.io` [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/9b510df35b57946d843ffc34cf23fdcfc84c5220/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io) and the `native` implementation of `close` (for the fd) [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/9b510df35b57946d843ffc34cf23fdcfc84c5220/luni/src/main/native/libcore_io_Posix.cpp).

Comment: In the last link, you'd have to find the implementation of `close()` on line 429.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Yes, I saw that question—that discusses the state of the file descriptor after the `EIO` error; I'm interested in what *causes* the `EIO`, not what to do after the error occurs.  The implementation of `close()` is a system call inside the Linux kernel.

Comment: It seems associated with a bad inode, but spelunking the kernel code is taking a little longer than I thought...

Comment: Same here. I don't see any way `close` can return with `EIO` except for exotic filesystems. What filesystem type is the file in question on?

Comment: @R..: I don't know for sure, since this error occurred on a different user's device, but it was on an SD card.  My Android device's SD card is formattes as `vfat` (according to `mount(1)`), so I suspect that's what the user's SD card was likely formatted as.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the `EIO` comes from `bad_file_flush` in `fs/bad_inode.c`. It seems when the kernel has any failure accessing an inode, it transforms the open file description to a pseudo-open-file of with `bad_inode_ops` as its file ops. I can't find the code that does this for FAT-based filesystems, but perhaps there's some generic code.

As for the reason, it's probably something like attaching a USB cable and mounting the filesystem from an attached computer, removing the SD card, etc.

Comment: Since I unfortunately do not have access to my user's device, I won't really be able to know for sure what was going on, but until then, this seems like the most likely explanation.  After poking around the kernel sources for a while, it seems that `sys_close()` can only return 0, `-EINTR`, `-EBADF`, or the return value from the file system's `flush()` implementation, and `vfat` doesn't implement `flush()`.

Answer (score -1):

In general, you should always anticipate IOExceptions when closing streams. The code is very straightforward, but see here for the cleanest example Java can afford:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/156520/1489860

However, in your specific case, I imagine an exception is being thrown because it appears you are changing the value of the InputStream in the *unzipOrPassthrough(InputStream)* method and then later trying to close it:

```
        if (entry == null) {
        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

When you later call close on the FileInputStream class, it probably freaks out because it is now a ByteArrayInputStream and no longer a FileInputStream.

Comment: It doesn't even make sense. If it is now a `ByteArrayInputStream` *object,* he *can't* 'later call close on the `FileInputStream` class'. He is closing the `ByteArrayInputStream`. Period. The part about 'now a `ByteArrayInputStream` and no longer a `FileInputStream` is nonsense. The reference is of type `InputStream.` References to objects can't remember what type of object they *were* pointing to.

Comment: `unzipOrPassthrough()` reads from the passed in input stream, but it doesn't close it.  It does reassign the local parameter `is`, but that has no effect on the original stream passed in.