# Is checking EINTR necessary for all operation of socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I researched and found that signal interruption can happen when programming with sockets. I have searched and found that in case of signal interruption, we should retry. That is, I have to catch the error and retry. I have to create socket like this.

```
int create_sock()
{
    int sock;

    while (1)
    {
        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        if (sock == -1)
        {
            if (errno == EINTR)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                perror("create_sock");
                exit(-1);
            }
        }

        break;
    }

    return sock;

}
```

Should I follow the above procedure in case of close, send and connect function?

Comment: `EINTR` can definitely happen during `send`.  You should read the 'man pages' for each of those syscalls; they will detail each of the error cases, and any special requirements.  E.g., IIRC, for `send`, you have to pass exactly the same args when you retry.

Comment: For `connect()` and `send()` and other similar operations (including `read()` and `write()`), you should consider wrapping the functions in a retry loop. The case of `close()` is trickier — it's probably best to assume that it succeeded and the descriptor isn't available when the call returns, even if `errno == EINTR`. I don't think your loop structure is good; it should be more like `while ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) { if (errno != EINTR) { perror("…"); exit(1); } }`. That has 5 lines in the body of the loop instead of 14 (ignoring the braces around the body of the loop).

Comment: See [`close()` is not closing socket properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730477/close-is-not-closing-socket-properly) and [If `close(2)` fails with EIO, will the file descriptor still be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297001/if-close2-fails-with-eio-will-the-file-descriptor-still-be-deleted).  There may also be other relevant Q&A on SO.

Comment: Note: [`socket()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) will not be interrupted by a signal in any [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socket.html)y system. For Linux in particular, you can check the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html) whether a call can return with an EINTR error or not.

Answer (score 4):

*Is checking EINTR necessary for all operation of socket?* Yes, ideally you should check. Not only `socket()` there are many system call which reports `EINTR` ERRORS if signal occurred while the system call was in progress.

From manual page of `signal(7)`

> **Interruption of system calls and library functions  by  signal
>          handlers**  If  a  signal  handler  is  invoked while a system call or
>          library function call is blocked, then either:
>
> ```
>    * the *call is automatically  restarted  after  the  signal
>      handler returns*; or
>
>    * the call fails with the error **EINTR**.
> ```
>
> If a blocked call to one of the  *following*  interfaces  is
>          interrupted  by  a  signal  handler, *then the call will be
>          automatically restarted after the signal  handler  returns*
>          if  the  SA_RESTART flag was used; otherwise the call will
>          fail with the error `EINTR`:
>   **Socket interfaces:** `accept`(2),  `connect`(2),  `recv`(2),
>                `recvfrom`(2),  `recvmsg`(2),  `send`(2),  `sendto`(2),  and
>                `sendmsg`(2), unless a timeout has  been  set  on  the
>                socket (see below).

Comment: That is true for many system calls (and, as cited, most socket-related system calls), but *not* for `socket(2)` in particular. The general rule of thumb for system calls is: if it may block for some indefinite period of time, then `EINTR` is a potential cause of error. But `socket(2)` never has reason to block since it is simply allocating some control structures within the kernel. As @lockcmpxchg8b noted in a comment under the question above, check the manual page for each system call.