# check if fclose() fails and return specific error

Tags: c, gcc, fclose

So, I tried to find an answer to this question unsuccessfully.

I know what to do and how to manage such a case - by using fluss/NULL etc. afterward. But checking it is tricky to me.

So, basically:

```
open some file(successfully) - let's call the pointer: file.
after some code running...
fclose(file);
```

Now, how can I check after(before it's also an option) closing the file - that it really happened?

What is the condition? By demand, I need to handle this case by printing some specific errors.

Comment: The return value?

Comment: Check the return value of `fclose`?

Comment: [fclose manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html): "Upon successful completion, 0 is returned.  Otherwise, EOF is
       returned and errno is set to indicate the error"

Comment: @kaylum so what is the condition i need to make?

Comment: in that case i need to report on any problem, includes fclose unsuccessfully.

Comment: `int r = fclose(); if (!r) { /* success */ } else { /* fail */ }`

Comment: @kaylum i am not familiar with C so much, so what u saying that before i close i need to do that, if succes - in that command the file closed? or i need to do again fclose(). another thing r== EOF in your case? thank you

Comment: Related: [If `close(2)` fails with EIO error, will the file descriptor still be deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7297001/15168)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following snippet:

```
#include <errno.h> 

if(fclose(file) != 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error closing file: %s", strerror(errno));
}
```

From the man pages, we see that an error in closing a file using `fclose()` sets the global variable `errno` to a value indicating what error occurred.  The function `strerror()` takes this value of `errno` and outputs a string to help indicate what the error actually was.

Comment: i shouldt do fclose(file) again, right? thank's alot.\

Comment: @Shay: No, you absolutely cannot use the pointer `file` again after calling `fclose`, no matter what the return value is. This is a use-after-free/double-free type bug and has really dangerous consequences.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE last question:) if was doing fclose(file) during the program and was an error in fclose() - the program continues? what's happening without checking it while error ?

Comment: That's up to you what to do. The only meaningful way `fclose` can fail is if some sort of error happens on the storage medium (possibly remote) that's not detected until close time. This kind of error could equally happen *after `fclose` reports success* due to cache architecture, unless you call `fflush` and `fsync(fileno(file))` (latter is POSIX not basic C and operates on underlying fd) before `fclose`, in which case you would ensure that the data has already been committed safely and `fclose` "can't fail" (and any error it returns could be ignored since you already confirmed write).

Comment: So, if you don't want to get into managing obscure low-level device/medium failure in your application, there's really nothing you even need to check. But if you do care, you probably should use `fsync` to commit before closing rather than looking for an error from `fclose`. None of this can be done entirely portable because the idea that there's a robust persistent storage medium is itself not entirely portable.

Comment: The standard doesn't explicitly say what you can and can't do with the stream after fclose fails. So I guess it is undefined by omission to try and call fclose again